# How to compile TensorFlow binary to use AVX2, AVX512F, FMA?

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, installation, cpu

When I call `tf.Session()` in TensorFlow, I obtain the following warning message:

> I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>   AVX512F FMA

My questions are:

1. How can I solve this? In particular, I wish to be able to keep the current TensorFlow version (1.12.0)
2. Will I obtain a considerable gain considering that I work on GPU?

I use Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. I do not know how to keep 1.12.0, however the Tensorflow page has a good build guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#setup_for_linux_and_macos
2. According to [comments](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7257#issuecomment-303861064) from this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7257) at the Tensorflow github project, no. Quote:

> From my experiments I found CPU-optimized GPU TF doesn't boost the performance significantly, but it can make the CPU cooler.